# Can Ambari blueprints be used for creating a Cloudera cluster or is puppet/chef/ansible type tools more suitable for CDH cluster

Tags: cloudera

I am looking at configuration management options for Cloudera clusters. It looks like Ambari blueprints is suitable for this for a HDP cluster but there is nothing similar for Cloudera. Is it better to use infrastructure configuration management tools like Puppet,Chef,etc. I am after a script-based solution rather than a UI wizard. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for the Cloudera Manager REST API:

http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/cm_intro_java_api.html